# how to run task on specified time using node-schedule?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, cron-task

I want to run node task every day 8AM using node-schedule package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule but instead of everyday 8AM its running every minute. what is the correct method that i can apply to rule to achieve my task ? we are using `node-schedule` on linux not sure if format is different in that case.

cron.js

```
var cronSchedule = require('node-schedule');

module.exports = function CronJob() {
    var rule = new cronSchedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.hour = 8;
    var dailyJob = cronSchedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
    console.log('Testing 8AM');
            async.eachSeries(directories, function (dir, cb1) {
                var dir = __dirname + dir;
                // get files for the directory
                });
            }, function (err, fileInfos) {
                if (err) {
                    console.info('error', err);
                    return;
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: From documentation: *"Note: It's worth noting that the default value of a component of a recurrence rule is null (except for second, which is 0 for familiarity with cron). If we did not explicitly set minute to 0 above, the message would have instead been logged at 5:00pm, 5:01pm, 5:02pm, ..., 5:59pm. Probably not what you want."*

Comment: that make sense i added `rule.minute = 0` and that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute task automatically and it will be recurring then you can try below code:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var scheduleFunction = schedule.scheduleJob('0 8 * * *', function(){
  console.log('Yeah ! i did.'));
});
```

The above code will be executed daily at 08:00 AM.

Or if you want to execute code once at the start of each quarter then try below code:

```
var myRule = {hour: 0, minute: 0, dayOfWeek: 1, month: [0, 3, 6, 9]};
var scheduleFunction = schedule.scheduleJob(myRule, function(){
  console.log('will execute every quarter'));
});
```